# bodyparser does not work on nextjs 13.3.0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

this is my route for sigin. but the body is not parsed and it content is like : { stream: undefined, source: null, length: null }

api/signin/route.ts

```
export function POST(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  NextResponse.json({ name:req.body.username });
}
```

i am sure the data is sent correctly with Content-Type:'application/json' header . the problem  is with body parser but i do not know have to fix it.
i already try to export default this code in my route.ts,

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: true,
  },
};
```

but this does not solve the problem.
any body can help me here?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new routes, you need to call `await request.json()`

No need for bodyparser.

See docs here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers#request-body

Comment: What about pages router?